# How To Make Pointers that Point to Each Member of a List

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a list. Each element of the list is a struct.

```
struct A
{
   int size;
}
```

The data looks like:

```
list[0]->size = a number.
```

How can I assign a pointer to each member of the list?

```
int *p;
for(i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
{
  p = &list[i];
}
```

That won't work since I am assigning only one pointer to the last element of the list. Should I make a list of pointers?

This should solve the XY problem.
**How do I create pointers for every element of my list?**

EDIT:
List looks like this

```
A **list;
```

I want to sort by pointers instead of by structures so that it is faster.

Trying this now:

```
A ***p = (A***) malloc(sizeof(A***));

for(i = 0; i < listLength; i++)
    p[i] = &list[i];

for(i = 0; i < listLength; i++)
    printf( p[i]->size); // Error.
```

Comment: This sounds like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it exactly that you want to accomplish?

Comment: `list[i]` is already a pointer to each element. You're asking the wrong question.

Comment: I can't help noticing that your example struct doesn't have a link member to point to the next struct instance in the list. Without link pointers somewhere, you don't have a linked list. Is that what you're asking about? - Probably not as you seem to be using an array, not a linked list, but then again you haven't `malloc`d memory for that array above - you seem to be using an uninitialized pointer as if it were an array.

Comment: I actually malloc, I just didn't want to bore anyone with trivial stuff.

Comment: I think I saw it and it looked promising, but it was deleted before I could fully read it.

Comment: @Mike - I should withdraw - I'm too tired and making stupid mistakes that are probably confusing things even more.

Comment: Do you really need to (m,c)alloc a struct? I can see needing to allocate some of the members if they are pointers, but the pointer to a struct itself can just be set to point to the definition, and go from there.   `LIST_t list, *pList;`  then in someFunc(), `pList = &list;`

Comment: Mike, look ***[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/522067/645128)*** for what looks like a very good example.  And you are right, there was a good example up before that person took it down, @Micheal.yxd is also on the way to a good example.  You were also correct in that I was not on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

you can create array of pointer like:
`struct A *arr_pointer[N]`

basically, you link struct should like that:

```
struct A {
    int size;
    struct A *next;
};
```

Comment: You have identified the right concept, it is the basis, I believe, for what would satisfy the OP's requirement.  [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/522067/645128)

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
} A, *pA;

typedef struct {
    int size;
} B, *pB;

//and so on...

//Now your list can be a collection of these
typedef struct {
    A a;
    B b;
    //additional members if defined
} LIST;

LIST list[20], *pList;  //[edited to make array of LIST]
//prototype List function

 LIST * updateList(LIST *a); 

int main(void)
{
   pList = &list[0];  //[edit to init pointer to array of lists
   //access and use pointers to list as necessary
   LIST *b = updateList(pList);
   //Use the updated list here
   printf( "b[0].a.size is: %d\n" , b[0].a.size);
   printf( "b[1].a.size is: %d\n" , b[1].a.size);
   printf( "b[2].a.size is: %d\n" , b[2].a.size);
   printf( "b[3].b.size is: %d\n" , b[3].b.size);
   printf( "b[4].b.size is: %d\n" , b[4].b.size);
   printf( "b[5].b.size is: %d\n" , b[5].b.size);

   return 0;
}

LIST * updateList(LIST *a)
{
    //do some manipulations to LIST here...
       a[0].a.size=1;
       a[1].a.size=2;
       a[2].a.size=3;
       //and so on.
       a[3].b.size=4;
       a[4].b.size=5;
       a[5].b.size=6;
       //and so on.
    return a;
}
```

Will this work for you?

Comment: I think you are doing something else. I just need to have p0...pn pointers for every element in my list[0..n]

Comment: define an array of LIST.  `LIST list[20], pList;`  Then `pList = &list[0];`.  new you have a pointer for every element in your array of lists.  I may be completely missing the point, but this architecture should support an array of structure member pointers.   If I have missed the point, please give out a few more clues.  Sometimes I can be thick :) (see edited answer)

Comment: Mike, (repeated from above comment) look ***[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/522067/645128)*** for what looks like a very good example.  And you are right, there was a good example up before that person took it down, @Micheal.yxd is also on the way to a good example.  You were also correct in that I was not on the right path.  win some, lose some.  Good luck!