# Bundling Malloc Calls

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, malloc, nodes

I was browsing SO and found [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522010/how-do-i-build-a-onetwothree-linked-list-with-a-minimum-number-of-assignment-ope) that raised a question for me.

```
struct node* BuildOneTwoThree() {
struct node *list = malloc(3 * sizeof(struct node));

list[0].data = 1;
list[0].next = list+1;
list[1].data = 2;
list[1].next = list+2;
list[2].data = 3;
list[2].next = NULL;

return list;}
```

I'm trying to understand how this call to malloc works and what it returns. Did it return an array of pointers? How does that work out, I didn't expect malloc to work in this way?

This seems to guarantee that the memory indices of the individual structs are one after another which I imagine could be a powerful or useful tool.

Also after such a call to malloc would it be okay to initialise the array indices as

```
list[0] = (struct node) {1, list +1};
```

Note: struct node is defined as,

```
  struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *next;};
```

Comment: It returns a pointer to `3 * sizeof(struct node)` bytes of allocated memory.

Comment: Why is it that I can index those pointers using array indices?

Comment: Because `list[i]` is equivalent to `*(list+i)`.

Comment: The space returned by `malloc()` in the first call is big enough to hold an array of 3 `struct node`, and the memory pointed at is sufficiently well aligned that it is safe to cast it to a `struct node *` and use it as an array of 3 `struct node` values.  The C standard requires that guarantee of 'sufficiently well aligned'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct node *list = malloc(3 * sizeof(struct node));
```

==> created a memory of three node structure size and list is pointed to the beginning of the memory storage. It means **list=&list[0] or *list = list[0], list+1=&(list[1]) or *(list+1)=list[1], list+2=&(list[2]) or *(list+2)=list[2]**

```
list[0] = (struct node) {1, list +1};
```

==> Yes, you can do that way. Here is my modification as that way, it worked fine:

```
struct node* BuildOneTwoThree() {
    struct node *list = (struct node *)malloc(3 * sizeof(struct node));

    list[0] = { 1, list + 1 };
    list[1] = { 2, list + 2 };
    list[2] = { 3, NULL };
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` returns a pointer to a memory region with the specified size.

The argument `3 * sizeof(struct node)` says the region size is able to store 3 `node` structures.

Pointers and indices in arrays are interchangeable, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4622461/4288486).